# php javascript place script in a file

Tags: javascript, php

I tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
  var cdata = <?php echo json_encode($cdata); ?>;
</script>
```

it works fine. I'm trying to place the script in a file:

```
var cdata = <?php echo json_encode($cdata); ?>;
```

and then access it with:

```
<script src="crewjs.php"   type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but that's not working. Here's the error from the console:

```
crew.js:186 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ldm' of null
at monthOnly (http://www.example.com/abc/public/js/crew.js:186:15)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick     http://www.example.com/abc/public/crew.php:3021:112)
```

I think the clue here is Cannot read property 'ldm' of null, it's not seeing the object.  The file is being found when I check sources and network

Comment: Do you get an error in the developer console? ("*That's not working*" is a bit too vague to know exactly what's going on...)

Comment: Why don't you just [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) the file?

Comment: I'm trying to pass a php array $cdata to javascript

Comment: Question: can I do this with a control file?  I have a abc.php file that I use to render forms.  Can I start the file with the <?php HEADER....;  Do all my server side stuff.  end php with ?> and then echo out the data I want to pass to javascript with var jsdata = <?php echo json_encode($phpdata); ?>; ??

Comment: @DCR do you read or just blatantly ignore suggestions? You're over complicating what you're trying to do. Just run a `$.getJSON(...)` call to a PHP file that's spitting out valid json.

Comment: @Darren I blatantly ignore answers I don't understand.  I'm new to this and I don't understand how to use $.getJSON(...)  I looked at the documentation and didn't understand what to do.  Would you like to provide some content with your answer or do you just blatantly spit out half form clues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send a Javascript header at the very beginning of the PHP file to inform the page that the PHP script is outputting a JavaScript file.

```
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
```

Also the final output of the PHP script needs to be a valid .js file, whatever the PHP outputs must conform to valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: I tried this as my file:  <?php
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript"); 
var cdata =  echo json_encode($cdata);
 ?>;  and got a 500(internal server error)

Comment: @DCR because that isn't valid PHP. What you want is something like [**this**] (https://eval.in/673017)

Comment: still don't understand the $.getJSON().  I don't have a json file to load just a complicated array of arrays in $cdata.  Anyway, the rest of this was helpful.  Thanks.